# Why do Chinese auto path URLs become something else?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I have a Drupal 7 site with i18n on it. There are lots of languages. The problem is that if you save a node that is in Chinese, and you select auto path, then the title that was, for example, /空氣清淨機 will be changed to /kong-qi-qing-jing-ji.

What exactly is this process called? Is it an "English alphabet" version of the Chinese text?

Comment: This looks to me like the name of the character's. i guess it's understandable, for those who can read the arabic letters .. On my site, the path is stays in the chinese charters', like the title, can you provide more information about your setup ? - What contenttype translation option did you choose ? (i use activated, with translations and fixed language in the extended language options)
- Do you use chinese simplified as language ?

Comment: We use Simplified Chinese for China, and Traditional for Taiwan. This is happening with both. And you should be able to test it by enabling "pathauto" and saving any node with "automatically generate path alias" checked.

Comment: what translation option do you have selected for the affected contenttypes ?

Comment: It is pinyin 拼音.. I think it is understandable for Chinese who speak Mandarin.

Comment: @coderama : merci (= FRENCH for 'thank you' ...) for the accept! Sorry it took 3 months to discover your question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you are describing in your question is called ***transliteration***.

The reason for what you see happening in your site, might be because you're using the [Transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> Provides one-way string transliteration (romanization) and cleans file names during upload by replacing unwanted characters.
>
> Generally spoken, it takes Unicode text and tries to represent it in US-ASCII characters (universally displayable, unaccented characters) by attempting to transliterate the pronunciation expressed by the text in some other writing system to Roman letters.

Here is a sample of what this module does for "**file names**":

[image]

However, it can also be used to transforms an URL like `mydomain.com/последние-новости-в-Украине-и-мире` in something like `mydomain/poslednie-novosti-v-Ukraine-i-mire`. To do so, you also need to enable the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module. After that, go to the Pathauto setting page and check "Transliterate prior to creating alias". For more details on that, refer to "[D7 Pathauto transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/node/1163118)". **Attention**: this does not "fix" already created aliases (those need to be deleted and recreated).

**Note**: There is also a [transliteration](/questions/tagged/transliteration) tag on drupal.SE (with only 4 questions using it though ...).